# AngularJS isn't loading ngStorage or any module

Tags: angularjs

I know this is a common issue, but I have a project i'm porting over to Angular and none of the modules I need to load inside the app (namely ngStorage) are loading. I continue to get this error in the console log:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ICSPortalLoginAuth due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngStorage due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngStorage' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ngStorage
    at http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:68:12
    at http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:2015:17
    at ensure (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:1939:38)
    at module (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:2013:14)
    at http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4503:22
    at forEach (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4487:5)
    at http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4504:40
    at forEach (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4487:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngStorage&p1=Error%…ules%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdevel1.local.com%2Fjs%2Fng%2Fangular.js%3A4487%3A5)
    at http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:68:12
    at http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4526:15
    at forEach (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4487:5)
    at http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4504:40
    at forEach (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4487:5)
    at createInjector (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:4409:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:1691:20)
    at bootstrap (http://devel1.local.com/js/ng/angular.js:1712:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ICSPortalLoginAuth&…rap%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdevel1.local.com%2Fjs%2Fng%2Fangular.js%3A1712%3A12)
```

ngStorage is loaded in the header before AngularJS or my Angular model:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/ng/angular.js'></script>
<script src='js/ngres/LoginAuth.js'></script>
```

And ngStorage is declared in the App declaration

```
var app = angular.module("Devel1", ['ngStorage']);
```

I am not entierly clear on what else could be causing this. There are other JavaScript dependencies being loaded that could cause interference, namely jQuery and jspdf. Could these be interfering with the module loader?

I'm stumped as to what the cause could be here. I remove the module and the code works (whatever little code there is) as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Please load angular script before loading ngStorage script and see....
This might work fine